# Javascript Event firing with page load

Tags: javascript, events, load, prototypejs, hidden-field

im trying to get hidden rows to show when the page is loaded depending on which radio button is checked, have the functions working for the on click event but can't seem to get it to work for on 'dom:loaded' event which i need for an edit page and can't figure out why, any help would be great

```
      $("content").observe('dom:loaded', function(event){
        if ($("organisation_contact_is_user_yes").checked){
            $$('.1').invoke('show');
            $$('.2').invoke('hide');
        }
        if ($("organisation_contact_is_user_no").checked){
            $$('.1').invoke('hide');
            $$('.2').invoke('show');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is this jQuery or some other framework? Because this doesn't look like jQuery.

Comment: is Prototype, should have put that sorry

Comment: Instead of using frameworks that you don't understand, why not learn basic javascript(cause this is what you need)? try `window.onload = function() { //put your code here }`

Comment: If the function getting called? Also why see if no is checked, wouldn't it be one or the other. Use an else.

Comment: its a function for an edit page so on the creation page when one of the radio buttons is checked hidden fields are shown, now i'm creating the edit page in which i need to observe which button is checked so that the hidden fields are automatically shown without needing to click the radio buttons again

Answer (score 0):

You listen for the 'dom:loaded' event on the document:

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function(event) {
    // anything you want to execute once the dom's ready
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the function needs to refer to the dom loaded framework. checking the no is unchecked wont make any difference. 
change every bracket to a { sign, works for me